# Django class UpdateView

Tags: django, django-views

I have this view and I use this code

```
class post_Wells(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Wellinfo
    template_name = 'Home/WELLINFO/detailw2.html'
    form_class = NewWells
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user== post.author:
            return True
        else:
            return True
```

everything works good, but I want to send other data from this class

for example I want to render this text:

```
    context ={
    'Mytext': 'This well is Open'}
```

how to do it inside this class?

Comment: Override get_context_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by overriding a method for the context, `get_context_data`.

You should bookmark this site; http://ccbv.co.uk/

Docs for this specific view are here; http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#get_context_data

And taking into account good practice, your class would become;

```py
class PostWells(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    form_class = NewWells
    model = Wellinfo
    template_name = 'Home/WELLINFO/detailw2.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user== post.author:
            return True
        else:
            return True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Insert your data into the context dict."""
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['Mytext'] = 'This well is Open'

        return context
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this using the [`get_context_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).

```
class post_Wells(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Wellinfo
    template_name = 'Home/WELLINFO/detailw2.html'
    form_class = NewWells
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user== post.author:
            return True
        else:
            return True
    
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['Mytext'] = 'This well is Open'
         return context
```